# Unable to connect to amazon server using putty

Tags: amazon-ec2, putty

I am trying to connect to EC2 server using putty with the help of .pem. It is giving me an error:
Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: public key)

I have created a .ppk through puttygen. Still facing the same problem.

Can any one help me with the solution.

Answer (score 4):

This usually means that there was a problem with how the pem file was converted to a ppk file, or that the pem file was not the right one to begin with. Make sure you followed the instructions for using puttygen correctly. There is an example here: [Convert PEM to PPK file format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190667/convert-pem-to-ppk-file-format)

Alternatively, use a windows ssh client that uses pem files directly. Two options are:

1. [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) - it includes an ssh command line client.
2. [Poderosa](http://poderosa.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: The client had provided an invalid host to connect. He gave a perfect one and the .pem file worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

U need a private key to connect to the server, the key U have probably is a public key, so U need to generate a private key in puttygen.

Comment: The client had provided an invalid host to connect. He gave a perfect one and the .pem file worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, you use Ubuntu AMI. Should be user name - ubuntu. 
Link: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html#TroubleshootingInstancesConnectingPuTTY

Answer (score 1):

For those searching, I had this issue but the latest authentication method was not supported by the old version of Putty. Upgrading Putty allowed me to connect.

I downloaded the latest Putty from the official website of Putty; then it required to uninstall, so I backed up by finding the key in the registry for:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER > Software > SimonTatham

By clicking on that entry and choosing `File > Export` and saved to desktop, this contains all the data and settings for Putty should something go wrong during uninstall.

[image: putty backup]

Now with Putty backed up, you can uninstall Putty (CCleaner is a good option), and when it asks if you want to remove the sessions click NO, otherwise it will wipe the data, but fortunately you have the data backed up to the registry by this point.

Finally, now you can install the latest version of Putty. The latest version of Putty has the necessary authentication methods that AWS uses.