# EC2 - Unable to login with ec2-user

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a AWS micro instance and I had no problems logging into the instance using ec2-user until now. I changed some permissions for ec2-user (basically removed the www group it was added to and again added that group). Now I am locked out of the instance. The error I am getting is:

Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent:publickey)

I have checked the following and everything seems to be in place:

1. My IP is updated in AWS security groups
2. My key (.ppk) is the same that I have been using for months
3. My security group has 80 and 442 enabled

Please help... this is really bothering me big time!

Comment: I presume you mean 443, not 442? SSH uses port 22 by default, it that enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting an error from the SSH service so you can be sure that this is not a firewall issue.

Its hard to know exactly what you did, but you may have inadvertently broken access to the file that stores the allowed public keys `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. This file only works with very limited permissions.

There is a way to recover from this, but it does involve several steps.

1. Start a new instance, can be micro, its only going to stay on for a bit.
2. Stop your current instance, detach the root volume and attach it to the new instance.
3. Mount the volume, fix permissions on the authorized_keys file.
4. Unmount, and detach the volume, reattach to original instance.

If everything is set up correctly, your key should work again on your existing instance.

Comment: thanks for your comments. ultimately i had to start a brand new instance and copy things over to that. the old one got too messed up i guess

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24587443/aws-disconnected-no-supported-authentication-methods-available-server-sent) from 9 months but it looks like someone had a similar issue. If you're using IAM, make sure your inline policy has EC2 access allowed.

Answer (score 0):

If the `ec2-user` somehow gets corrupted, you can add an additional user. This approach does not require mounting the volume, but instead relies on modifying the `User Data` in the EC2 console.

See https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/execute-user-data-ec2/

For example, you can create a new key:

`ssh-keygen -t rsa -C private.key -f private.key -q -N ""`

Then use the following `User Data`:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="//"
MIME-Version: 1.0

--//
Content-Type: text/cloud-config; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="cloud-config.txt"

#cloud-config
cloud_final_modules:
- [scripts-user, always]

--//
Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="userdata.txt"

#!/bin/bash
USER=additional-user  # 1
adduser $USER 
echo "$USER ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" >> /etc/sudoers.d/cloud-init 
mkdir /home/$USER/.ssh 
echo "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAA....A38MHe0KAzY9Ob private.key" >> /home/$USER/.ssh/authorized_keys  # 2
--//
```

1. Replace `additional-user` with a username of your choice
2. Replace whatever is inside the double quotes with the `private.key.pub` contents that you just generated.

You should then be able to ssh into the instance:

```
chmod 600 private.key
ssh -i private.key additional-user@<ec2 public ip>
```

Remember to clean up your `User Data` so that it doesn't keep running on subsequent launches. Also deprovision the additional user (or at least remove its sudo access), once ec2-user is working again.

For more detailed instructions, see: https://bitbucket.org/thorntechnologies/sftpgateway-public/wiki/Locked%20out%20of%20EC2%20instance