# AWS EC2 2022 - Disconnected: No supported authentication method available

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-ami

I am trying to launch AWS EC2 instance with Ubuntu AMI. The username is ubuntu.
Before the launch, I created my key using .ppk option checked:

[image: AWS PPK Key download]

After launching EC2, I can see the key I selected is showing under **Key pair name**.

I opened putty, pasted hostname as ubuntu@ec2-blah-blah-blah-blah.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com and selected the .ppk file under SSH > Auth > Browse and then clicked open and get the error message as below:

[image]

I have literally gone mad as I am unable to figure out why the simplest thing isnt working.

Need some help, thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS - Disconnected : No supported authentication methods available (server sent :publickey)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24587443/aws-disconnected-no-supported-authentication-methods-available-server-sent)

Comment: Question belongs to serverfault. Anyways always mention AMI ID, OS version. It's clear backend sshd daemon doesn't support native ssh-rsa algorithm. Consider using new ssh client or upgrade to newer version of putty.

Answer (score 5):

Upgrading Windows Putty to 0.77 solved the problem.

Comment: This was part of it for me - the other part was opening the .ppk private key and re-saving it with the new version of putty.

Answer (score 0):

Hostname is only the ec2-blah-blah-blah-blah.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com, without ubuntu@.

Also there is this [article](https://medium.com/@omar.merghany95/how-to-solve-disconnected-no-supported-authentication-methods-available-server-sent-publickey-eb012ffbd159#:%7E:text=This%20error%20can%20occur%20under,session%20with%20an%20EC2%20instance.) for further investigation.

Comment: Even even hostname ec2-blah-blah-blah-blah.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com without ubuntu@, it does not work.