# disconnected no supported authentication methods available (server sent publickey) sent publickey gssapi keys with mic

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, centos, centos7, centos6

I can't connect to aws-ec2 centos. I get:

> disconnected no supported authentication methods available (server
>   sent publickey) sent publickey gssapi keys with mic

[image: Image for Error Message]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google server putty connect 'Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20294381/google-server-putty-connect-disconnected-no-supported-authentication-methods-a)

Answer (score 1):

Inside putty ssh we need to configure the ppk file. they only we can able to access the server through ssh. make sure you're mapped correctly. and check again.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at Image in Error Msg I think you are entering wrong user name try `centos` not `root`.

Hope it Helps!

Comment: did you add correct ssh keys ? is the security group allowing to connect via port 22 ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the `.pem` private key file downloaded from the EC2 console when you create a keypair is not compatible with PuTTY by default! Putty expects a converted `.ppk` file for keypair authentication over SSH. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190667/convert-pem-to-ppk-file-format) for a tutorial on how to do this.