# Where to download .ppk file from aws lightsail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

Where to download .ppk file from aws light sail

Hi , **i want to create a new ftp account for my website in aws swerver** . When i check the aws server in lightsail section i can see my magento instances (web & db instance ).

Now i want to c**onnect to my file using filezila** . What i have to do ? I am checking Internet for some time but everything is confusing

What i  did is i go to https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/webapp/account/keys then ssh key then download the key . But now how i can connect throuh filezila . The downloaded file is .pem file .

Please help

Answer (score 6):

AWS by default provides the key in pem file, all you need to convert pem to ppk.

> PuTTY does not natively support the private key format (.pem)
>   generated by Amazon EC2. PuTTY has a tool named PuTTYgen, which can
>   convert keys to the required PuTTY format (.ppk). You must convert
>   your private key into this format (.ppk) before attempting to connect
>   to your instance using PuTTY.

**To convert your private key**

- From the Start menu, choose All Programs, PuTTY, PuTTYgen.
- Under Type of key to generate, choose RSA.
- Choose Load. By default, PuTTYgen displays only files with the extension .ppk. To locate your .pem file, select the option to display files of all types.

[image]

[image]
You can check for conversation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html#putty-private-key) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190667/convert-pem-to-ppk-file-format).

Comment: really thank you . I will check this and let you know

Comment: hi i did asper mentioned . and i save the private key . i dont know even i have to save public or private key . After saving the private key i try to connect using filezila but there is error . What i have to write in User : filed of filezila ? . How i can understand my username . please help

Comment: https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/log-in-to-your-bitnami-application-running-on-amazon-lightsail

Comment: its depend on AMI, but you get one from AWS console ec2 connect

Comment: Error: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
Error: Could not connect to server

Comment: could you please tell steps to connect ftp .  I am new to aws . I have already a ftp connection to my files . That ppk file is given by my supporting company . Now they are not in contact . so i am creating a new ftp to give other company they are doing work for my website

Comment: First try to connect using `ssh` with same key if ssh working rest should work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199567/discussion-between-abilash-er-and-adiii).